# How can I tell what the "which" in the Complex Sentence refer to?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

I feel confused to the following sentence:

> The interpreter automatically binds the *instance* **upon which** the *method* is invoked to the *self* parameter.

I have two ways to get the meaning:

- The interpreter binds the *instance* upon **the method**,  which (the method) is invoked to the *self* parameter.
- The interpreter binds the *instance*. upon **the instance** , the method is invoked to the *self* parameter.

Which one is right? Or there are other ways to understand?

And the *bind something upon something*  is a idiom or phrase?

Comment: Your second sentence is correct, it is the instance.  This is the correct grammatical sequence.  The majority of native speakers stick the preposition at the end, especially in speech, which makes it easier to see this:  The interpreter automatically binds the instance which (that) the method is invoked upon...

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. But the second sentence  is not completely right. According to Answer, The right way to understand is :  The interpreter binds the instance (upon which the method is invoked) to the self parameter.

Comment: We said the same thing.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method is invoked **upon** the *instance*.
>   The interpreter binds the instance **to** the self parameter.

How do you arrive at this parse? A couple of syntactic regularities help:

- A relative clause usually refers to the nearest preceding entity of the right type. In this case the noun phrase immediately preceding *upon which* is *the instance*, so that's probably its referent.
- A relative clause consists of two parts:

  1. A 'relative phrase' containing the relativizer—in this case the relative phrase is *upon which*. The relativizer itself is a sort of variable name which can be replaced by its referent, so in this case the relative phrase is equivalent to *upon the instance*.
  2. An ordinary finite clause with a "gap" in it somewhere: a place where a constituent is missing *which can be intelligibly replaced with the relative phrase*. In this case, you find a place you can put the relative phrase after *invoked*:

     ```
     [Upon the instance] the method is invoked _`  
     ↘ → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → ↘
                         the method is invoked [upon the instance]
     ```

It must be admitted however that this is an unusually difficult clause for a learner to parse. First, it's a complicated sentence (unnecessarily complicated, to my mind). Second, the relative phrase is a preposition phrase acting as a non-obligatory constituent, so there's not an obvious syntactic gap; that makes it hard to pin down where it belongs.

To see where the gap lies you really have to be intimately familiar with the technical terminology involved so you recognize what sort of role the phrase can play. You have to know, for instance, that *invoked* rarely takes a *to X* complement and *bound* rarely takes an *upon X* complement in present-day English, and that in descriptions of programming languages *bind* often takes a *to X* complement and that methods are sometimes *invoked **upon*** classes or instances. That's the sort of thing that only comes with practice in the field. Right now I'm actively learning Python myself, and it took me several seconds to figure out what the sentence means.

Comment: Thank you very much!  In the sentence, I always consider  the " upon which the method is invoked to the self parameter" is a complete subordinate clause. But I have learned Python,  I know what I understand to this sentence is wrong. So that's why I feel so confused and uncomfortable.

Comment: @Jesse Yah. I'd say "When *instance.method()* is invoked, the interpreter automatically binds *instance* to *method*'s 'self' parameter."